# Error : Aws.Translate() is not a constrauctor

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, angular5

i am going to use the AWS Translate in my angular 5 project and i am using  [aws-sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk)
and it give me error that Translate is not a constructor . 
here is my code

```
AWS.config.region = 'eu-central-1';
var ep = new AWS.Endpoint('https://translate.us-west-2.amazonaws.com');
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.Credentials("my access key", "my secrect key");
var translate = new AWS.Translate()
translate.endpoint = ep;
var params = {
  Text: "hello how Are you",
  SourceLanguageCode: 'fr',
  TargetLanguageCode: 'en'
};
translate.translateText(params, function (err, data) {
  console.log(err, data);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This means that Translate isn't part of the AWS SDK you are using. Translate was introduced in version `2.159.0` of the AWS JavaScript SDK, upgrade to that version or newer and it should work fine.

It's also not recommended that you have hard coded credentials in the browser, API operations that require an access key and secret key are best done on your backend. See: [Setting Credentials in a Web Browser](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-credentials-browser.html)

Comment: i am using the 2.211 version for SDK

Comment: @HassanAmjad are you using a custom build of the SDK? E.g. through https://sdk.amazonaws.com/builder/js/ or did you install it using npm/yarn?

Comment: i add custom one @Karl

Comment: can you please help me ?

Comment: Does your custom build include the translation service? If you send a link to it I can take a look.

Comment: yeah i add up the Translation service

Comment: how can i send the link its downloaded by me

Comment: you could upload it somewhere, like pastebin!

Comment: I tested locally and it works fine for me! (Although I get a NotAuthorizedException because I don't have the Translate preview enabled for my account). What exception do you get?

Comment: can you please Share your code ? i shall be thankful to you